# Can XDomainRequest be made to work with SSL?

Tags: ajax, ssl, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, xdomainrequest

I have code that uses Microsoft's XDomainRequest object in IE8. The code looks like this:

```
var url = "http://<host>/api/acquire?<query string>";  
var xdr = new XDomainRequest();  
xdr.onload = function(){  
    $.("#identifier").text(xdr.responseText);  
};  
xdr.open("GET", url);  
xdr.send();
```

When the scheme in "url" is "http://" the command works fine. However, when the scheme is "https://" IE8 gives me an "Access denied" JavaScript error. Both schemes work fine in FF 3.6.3, where I am, of course, using XmlHttpRequest. With both browsers I am complying with W3C Access Control. "http://" works cross origin for both browsers. So the problem is with IE8, XDomainRequest, and SSL.

The SSL certificate is not the problem. If I type https://`<host`>/ into the address bar of IE8, where `<host`> is the same as in "url" above, the page loads fine.

So we have the following:
- hitting https://`<host`>/ directly from the browser works fine;
- hitting https://`<host`>/api/acquire?`<query string`> via XDomainRequest is not allowed.

Can it be done? Am I leaving something out?

Answer (score 18):

Apparently, the answer is here: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ieinternals/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds)

Point 7 on this page says, "Requests must be targeted to the same scheme as the hosting page."

Here is some of the supporting text for point 7:

> "It was definitely our intent to prevent HTTPS pages from making
> XDomainRequests for HTTP-based resources, as that scenario presents a
> Mixed Content Security Threat which many developers and most users do
> not understand.
>
> However, this restriction is overly broad, because it prevents HTTP
> pages from issuing XDomainRequests targeted to HTTPS pages. While it’s
> true that the HTTP page itself may have been compromised, there’s no
> reason that it should be forbidden from receiving public resources
> securely."

It would appear at present that the answer to my original question is: YES, if the hosting page can use the "https://" scheme; NO, if it cannot.

Comment: fwiw, I'm having issues with XDR requests to https URLs, even when the hosting page is also served via https (and the requested domain is a subdomain of the hosting page.)  'Works when I use http for both, however.

Comment: I too have had no luck with XDR using https, even when the requesting page is also https. It simply trips the `onerror` event (a callback which is helpfully given zero information). I'm communicating between two virtual hosts on my development computer & have begun to wonder if that has anything to do with it (self-signed certificate?).

Comment: @SethBro yeah i am also wondering about a self-signed certificate in a project i'm currently working on.

Comment: If you use an invalid certificate (self-signed and not trusted) then yes, XDR will immediately fail the connection.

Comment: @EricLaw if it's self sign but trusted internally does that constitute an invalid certificate?

Comment: If the certificate is properly trusted, within its validity period, and bears the proper SubjectCN hostname, it will be treated as valid.

Comment: So happy to find this post, so thanks. The "Access Denied" error message is pretty vague.